Is it valid to use the Biot-Savart Law to estimate the induced magnetic field near a conductive surface due to an incident plane wave?
I have a scenario where a thin, finite-sized Perfect Electric Conductor (PEC) is illuminated by an incident plane wave, inducing surface currents on the PEC. I want to estimate the magnetic field near the surface (in the near-field region) based on these currents.
Using MATLAB, I can compute the surface current as a complex 3×p matrix (where 3 represents the xyz components and p is the number of mesh elements on the surface). My question is: can I use the Biot-Savart law to estimate the magnetic field at different locations near the surface, knowing that the surface current is available in this discrete form?
$$
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \sum_i \frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}_i) \times (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_i)}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_i|^3} \, \Delta S_i
$$
I understand that the Biot-Savart law is applied to steady (time-static) currents. However, in my case, the surface current from MATLAB is complex, as it accounts for the phase and amplitude due to the time-varying incident plane wave. Would the Biot-Savart law still apply to estimate the magnetic field from the magnitude of the current that is simulated from MATLAB?
or is there a better approach I should consider?

This looks like a scattering problem. The Biot-Savart law is not sufficient to solve the near field of the boundary, you need something more complicated, see, for example,  Eqs (7) and (8) in https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.15390/page/131/mode/2up.

@hyportnex,  From Balanis' book the field can be computed if we take the current as the source on the conductor. Since I have the current density simulated through MATLAB, do I still need to consider the boundary condition? I am happy to look over the equation you provided but the archived is offline.
